# Can someone explain me what this selector.select() method does?

Tags: java, networking, webserver, nio

Hi there,

I'm reading the book [Java Network Programming](http://sufuq.com/books/java/Java%20Network%20Programming,%204th%20Edition.pdf) to study a way of creating my own web server and i reached a page where it talks about multithreaded server and how to writing to it using the [echo protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc862) as an example (page 293).

Here is the code i'm talking about:

```
    ServerSocketChannel sChannel = null;
    Selector selector = null;
    try {
        sChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        ServerSocket echoServer = sChannel.socket();
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(PORT);
        selector = Selector.open();
        
        echoServer.bind(addr);
        sChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        sChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        System.out.println("Server running.");
    } catch (IOException e) {//If something goes wrong, the server must be stopped
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    while(true) {
        try {
            selector.select();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
```

And my question is about

```
selector.select()
```

because that method it's supposed to block the thread when there is no channel registered to this selector but i don't really know how it can create a new channel when a client tries to connect or how this channel is created and when. 
I tried reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select()) and [Java NIO by Ron Hitchens book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-nio/0596002882/ch04.html) but i didn't succeed, Can anyone explain me this please?

Comment: It doesn't create a new channel. This code doesn't get beyond unblocking when an incoming connection arrives. You have to call `acceot()` to get the new channel. NB This is terrible code from the exception handling point of view. If that's from the book, get a better book.

Comment: Hmm i see, thank you for your help buddy. Which other book do you recommend?

Comment: *Fundamental Networking in Java,* but then I did write it :-|

Comment: Again, thank you for your help, i will read it :)